# How to list all the tags for a repository in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I am looking for the list of the available releases on a GitHub repository. When I go to the releases tab, I only see few results and I have to scroll for ages to find what I am looking for.

Alternatively I can do this:

```
$ git ls-remote --tags https://github.com/python/cpython.git 2>&1 | \ 
     grep -P -o 'tags/v\K\d\.\d\.\d$' | sort -u
```

Is there a way to do the same on GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a list of all the tags on the repo main page: you need to click the dropdown "Branch: master" and switch to tags. Search by tag is also available there.

[image: screenshot]

Another way for getting old tags/releases: on the page https://github.com/python/cpython/releases (you mentioned it) you can append parameter to the url like this: https://github.com/python/cpython/releases?after=v1.2. Then you will get closely to the page you are searching.

Comment: Well, I have tried that, but the tag `v1.0.2` is not found and not visible on the list.